# How does one go about evaluating complex logic functions (logic gates circuits)?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I'm tasked with filling out a truth table (in the form of KM) of quite complex circuit and I'm not aware of any reasonably efficient method to do so - other than manually evaluating every possible input.

There must be some hidden pattern. The circuit should even be describable in a few words.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing out the equation and reducing it?

Comment: @TimWescott I did not find any really good reduction yet, but writing it out and trying to play with it at least a bit seems like the most reasonable way so far.

Comment: Seems impossible.  I could say start at A AND move to F.  OR simulate it.  OR write the equation.  OR realize it is 2 kmaps.  Redraw Y AND Z. I'd claim ever place lines cross is a short, because they did not use dots.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: I'm pretty sure they're using the rule that a "T" intersection is a connection and an "X" isn't.  The schematic doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: @TimWescott Can confirm.

Comment: @TimWescott Just teasing.  We are NOT going to do your homework.  There are lots of ways to proceed.  Write a big truthtable with columns for each gate: A XNOR B, etc..

Comment: by inspection, Y is 1 whenever: E is 0 and F is 1. That solved 16 combinations already.

Comment: Thanks alot guys! You already helped tremendously by basically assuring me that this is the correct way to proceed and that I'm not missing something really obvious. Pretty much everything I asked for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look for patterns. Note that the combination of XNOR and NOT appears three times, each with the same pattern of connections to two of the inputs. That makes it a good bet that A, C and E are one 3-bit input and B, D and F are another 3-bit input.

If I had to guess, I would start with some sort of magnitude comparator function.

Answer (score 1):

> any reasonably efficient method to do so - other than manually evaluating every possible input.

When you write the output as formula like

bool Y = (in[2] and in[1]) xor in[4];

Then you already have written this as valid C++ and only need to slap a loop around it this that goes through all possible `in`, and prints the results; the trick is to use std::bitset for in.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using bs = std::bitset<6>;
using out = std::cout;

bool valueY(const bs in) {
  return in[0] and in[1]; // put your actual logic expression here. Use () extensively!
}
int main() {
  for(unsigned long i = 0; i < (1 << 6); ++I) {
    bs current_in(i);
    bool y = valueY(current_in);
    out << "input " << current_in << " output " << y << "\n";
  }
}
```

You type that once, and it becomes by far the most time efficient method of generating the values in that table - you only need to rewrite r your calculation function.

If you actually want to generate the table as given in your problem, that's not really harder, just sightly more typing while programming. I'm typing C++ on my phone, which sucks, so I didn't fell like I needed to do that boring part of the programming.

Answer (score 0):

> The circuit should even be describable in a few words.

Why?

There are 64 possible input states, 2 outputs, and 6 internal nodes.  Draw a big table and work through it.  You can start at the inputs and work forward, or start at the outputs and work backwards.  Back in the day I found it easier to start at the outputs, but that's just me.